# Replicating the results of a Poisson GLM wth log link function

Tags: r, self-study, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I'm working on an example from the [book](https://www.crcpress.com/An-Introduction-to-Generalized-Linear-Models-Third-Edition/Dobson-Dobson-Barnett/p/book/9781584889502) "An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models 3rd Edition" by Dobson. I'm trying the exercise on page 69 which starts:

"The data in Table 4.5 show the numbers of cases of AIDS in Australia
by date of diagnosis for successive 3-months periods from 1984 to 1988." Which looks like this:

```
year1984 <- c(1,6,16,23)
year1985 <- c(27,39,31,30)
year1986 <- c(43,51,63,70)
year1987 <- c(88,97,91,104)
year1988 <- c(110,113,149,159)

rbind(year1984,year1985,year1986,year1987,year1988)
```

The task is to fit a generalized linear model to these data using the Poisson distribution, the log-link function and the equation: $log \lambda_i=\beta_1+\beta_2x_i$ The solution given for the Poisson regression model is:
 $ log\hat{\lambda_i}= 0.996 + 1.327 log_i$

But my attempt doesn't give me this:

```
x<-c(1:20)
y<-c(1,6,16,23,
     27,39,31,30,
     43,51,63,70,
     88,97,91,104,
     110,113,149,159)

m1 <- glm (y~x,family=poisson)
m1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are fitting `y~x`, but you should be fitting `y~log(x)` in order to match the model given for the solution; the log link transforms the left hand side of the equation, not the right hand side.  Try it and you'll see that you get the stated results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Though the log given in the first equation $(log\lambda_i)$ for the task is just for the link function correct?

Comment: Right, the link function handles that part of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a solution to a similar problem and found out that R has a handy way of specifying this within the *glm* function (works also for *glmer*) that worked really well for me:

```
family=poisson(link="log")
```

maybe it helps someone else as well.

Comment: Note that the log link is the default for the Poisson GLM in R, because the log link is the _canonical_ link function for a Poisson GLM.